# Remote Debug Java Application Running on server with intellij idea

Tags: spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, server, remote-debugging

I have a java spring boot 3 application that is in production using Docker my main AIM is to run it over server and debug it using IDEA's remote debug.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 4042 5005
ADD target/web-ui-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar web-ui-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD run.sh run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/run.sh"]
```

in sh i am running the jar with
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`

i spinned up the docker container and ran it locally in Docker exposing 4042 [to access in chrome] and 5005 [to use in IDEA's remote debug].

I got success connecting the remote debug.

[REMOTE DEBUG IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiPJo.png)

but when i am hitting 4042 over chrome it says 404 not found[404 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MVuH.png)

Q1. is it possible that my server runs over the internet at let's say [www.myself.com](http://www.myself.com) with 443 and 5005 port exposed so that i can remote debug with 5005 port in IDEA?

CAN ANYONE HELP ME? IF THIS GOES WELL THEN I'LL SETUP MY SERVER TO HAVE REMOTE DEBUG.

I am expecting help from fellow java devs.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a local environment, and debug it in your local IDE, without using either Docker or the remote server?